# Framework is not found. Linker command failed with exit code -1

Tags: ios, xcode, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I want to add Appsflyer framework in my project. Added by two ways

1. Downloaded the framework and imported it to project. Added in Linked Frameworks and Libraries. When i Compile it shows the error of "ld: framework not found AppsFlyer. Linker Command failed with exit code -1".
2. Tried with Cocoa pods. Created podfile and installed Appsflyer framework. 
   Here also i get the same error."ld: framework not found AppsFlyer. Linker Command failed with exit code -1".

Tried with all options from stackoverflow. By using Header search paths, Library search paths and framework search paths.Enabling Bitcode, Build Active Architecture only etc. Even though i get the same result.

Iam using Xcode 6.3 and tried with xcode 7.3 also.

Suggest me how to resolve the problem?  Thanks in advance.

[image][image]

Comment: whenever you see something in red color, delete those and add them back. ALso check you framework is listed in the build phases link with binary section.

Comment: i also get the same issue.  Did the same but no luck. @TejaNandamuri

Comment: After adding the framework, it is visible but it is not taking the reference of it. It is showing "Framework is not found".